# How to plot 4-D data embedded in a dataframe in Julia using a subplots approach?

Tags: matplotlib, dataframe, plot, julia

I have a Julia DataFrame where the first 4 columns are dimensions and the 5th one contains the actual data.

I would like to plot it using a subplots approach where the two main plot axis concern the first two dimensions and each subplot then is a contour plot over the remaining two dimensions.

I am almost there with the above code:

```
using DataFrames,Plots
# plotlyjs() # doesn't work with plotlyjs backend
pyplot()

X = [1,2,3,4]
Y = [0.1,0.15,0.2]
I = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
J = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

df = DataFrame(X=Int64[], Y=Float64[], I=Float64[], J=Float64[], V=Float64[] )
[push!(df,[x,y,i,j,(5*x+20*y+2)*(0.2*i^2+0.5*j^2+3*i*j+2*i^2*j+1)]) for x in X, y in Y, i in I, j in J]

minvalue = minimum(df[:V])
maxvalue = maximum(df[:V])

function toDict(df, dimCols, valueCol)
    toReturn = Dict()
    for r in eachrow(df)
        keyValues = []
        [push!(keyValues,r[d]) for d in dimCols]
        toReturn[(keyValues...)] = r[valueCol]
    end
    return toReturn
end

dict = toDict(df, [:X,:Y,:I,:J], :V )
M = [dict[(x,y,i,j)] for j in J, i in I, y in Y, x in X ]

yL = length(Y)
xL = length(X)

plot(contour(M[:,:,3,1], ylabel="y = $(string(Y[3]))", zlims=(minvalue,maxvalue)), contour(M[:,:,3,2]), contour(M[:,:,3,3]), contour(M[:,:,3,4]),
     contour(M[:,:,2,1], ylabel="y = $(string(Y[2]))", zlims=(minvalue,maxvalue)), contour(M[:,:,2,2]), contour(M[:,:,2,3]), contour(M[:,:,2,4]),
     contour(M[:,:,1,1], ylabel="y = $(string(Y[1]))", xlabel="x = $(string(X[1]))"), contour(M[:,:,1,2], xlabel="x = $(string(X[2]))"), contour(M[:,:,1,3], xlabel="x = $(string(X[3]))"), contour(M[:,:,3,4], xlabel="x = $(string(X[4]))"),
     layout=(yL,xL) )
```

This produces:
[image: subplots]

I remain however with the following concerns:

1. How do I automatize the creation of each subplot in the subplot call ? Do I need to write a macro ?
2. I would like each subplot to have the same limits in the z axis, but zlims seems not to work. Is zlims not yet supported ?
3. How do I hide the legend on the z axis on each subplot and plot it instead apart (best would be on the right side of the main/total plot) ?

**EDIT:**
For the first point I don't need a macro, I can create the subplots in a for loop, add them in a array and pass the array to the plot() call using the ellipsis operator:

```
plots = []
for y in length(Y):-1:1
    for x in 1:length(X)
        xlabel = y == 1 ? "x = $(string(X[x]))" : ""
        ylabel = x==1 ? "y = $(string(Y[y]))" : ""
        println("$y - $x")
        plot = contour(I,J,M[:,:,y,x], xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel, zlims=(minvalue,maxvalue))
        push!(plots,plot)
    end
end
plot(plots..., layout=(yL,xL))
```

Comment: use `clim` instead of `zlim`. `zlim` is for 3D plots.

Comment: Doesn't colorbar = false do the trick of hiding the legend? You could make a very thin and tall subplot on the far right with the colorbar on.

Comment: Thank you. `colorbar` works, but not `clims`. Still each subplot has different colour scale.

Comment: That's a bug in that case. Dang.

Comment: Yeah, it works for heatmap but not contour. Gotta fix.